# How to create a anchor link to different .php file?

Tags: php

I'm new to php and hope you can make me figure out whether I'm trying to do anything impossible.

I have two folders 'public' (root directory), and 'library' (all php files here), these folders are in same level of folder hierachy. my public/index.php is basically loading  another php file (say aa.php) which is in 'library' folder on the loadup. Now I need to create a anchor link to file call bb.php which is also inside library folder.

I tried create anchor as follows

```
echo "<a href="bb.php"> my bb file </a>
```

But I'm getting 404 error saying localhost/bb.php can not be accessed. I guess this is because bb.php file is not with in root directory and server is preventing direct access to this file.

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Thank you

Comment: You can't link to a file/script that is not in your publicly-accessible directory.

Comment: Your problem has nothing PHP related. With HTML file the problem would remain the same.

Comment: Learn the basics, try Google...

Answer (score 0):

If library/ and public/ are at the same level, the webserver will not be able to serve the files in library/. Typically, files in a library directory would be included by files in the public web folder.

If you need to use the bb.php directly, you will have to move it to public or a folder within public. And then from within public/bb.php you can include library files

`/* public/bb.php */

include("/path/to/webroot/library/file.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Move bb.php into the folder "public".